# how to update gridview based on dropdownlist item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web page that contains one Dropdownlist and Gridview.

Query is Dropdownlist will contains SQL Server database table list. When I select a table name from dropdownlist the Gridview needs to show entire table data and able to perform `edit, update, delete, cancel` actions.

When I click `edit`, Gridview need to show `Update` and `Cancel` buttons and it update should update dropdownlist table and also delete.

Please any one can help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebind your grid view on selected index changed of dropdown
like this

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridview.DataSource = dataSource;
    gridview.DataBind();
}
```

where datasource is your database query result

Comment: @user2128849 so if you got your answer then plz mark it as answer. it is good practice on stackoverflow to mark the answer so other can catch that easily.

Answer (score 0):

You must hook in changing dropdoenlist and then update your grid

```
protected void YourDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YouGridview.DataSource = YourdataSource;
    YouGridview.DataBind();
}
```